# Converting Sum of Trigonometric Functions into Product

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I know that $\sin x-\sin y=2\sin(\dfrac{x}{2}-\dfrac{y}{2})\cos(\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{y}{2}).$

I would like to know how to get this formula.

Comment: take L.H.S  let x= $x/2$+$x/2$ and do same for y and expand using double angle formula and simplify and on R.H.S use double angle formulas to expand it and simply the L.H.S=R.H.S so you get the answer there are several ways but this is easiest

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html  and http://planetmath.org/prosthaphaeresisformulas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\sin(a+b) = \sin(a) \cos(b) + \sin(b) \cos(a)
$$
and

$$
\sin(a-b) = \sin(a) \cos(b) - \sin(b) \cos(a)
$$

Apply these to $a = (x/2) - (y/2)$ and $b = (x/2) + (y/2)$, and add the two results. 
You'll get your formula.